# Why is TypeScript complaining that parameter has implicit type `any` when getCurrenUlr() returns a `Promise<string>`?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, typescript, protractor

I am using `protractor 4.x` with TypeScript. Using TypeScript `2.0`, the compiler complains in the following test:

```js
it('should have url', done=>{
  browser.getCurrentUrl().then((x)=>{
    // do something with x
  })
})
```

It is saying: `error TS7006: Parameter 'x' implicitly has an 'any' type.`
Yes, I know I can turn this off in the file, the `tsconfig.json` or explicitly set the typ, but my real question is **why?**

When I hover over `browser.getCurrentUrl()` it clearly says `(property) Webdriver.getCurrentUrl: () => webdriver.promise.Promise<string>` so, x should implicitly be of type `string`

## Repro steps

- clone `https://github.com/angular/protractor`
- [follow instructions for running examples](https://github.com/angular/protractor/tree/master/exampleTypescript)
- in the examples folder, set `noImplicitAny` to `true` in `tsconfig.json`
- add the test from above in the `spec.ts` file
- try compiling.

`tsconfig.json` (straight from [Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/exampleTypescript/tsconfig.json)):

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "declaration": false,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "outDir": "tmp",
        "types": ["node", "jasmine"]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "asyncAwait",
        "plugins.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you show your `tsconfig.json` contents?

Comment: will add it, but it's the out-of-the-box tsconfig from the Protractor example.

Comment: Okay, but the `noImplicitAny` is set to `false` in your config..?

Comment: Sorry, just copied it from the site. Fixing it now.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is because you need to **explicitly** give a type to the parameter `x`:

```
it('should have url', done=>{
  browser.getCurrentUrl().then((x: string)=>{
    // do something with x
  })
})
```

Comment: Unsure about why this answer has been downvoted when it answers OP's question correctly.

Comment: Yeah, I can read too. But `getCurrentUrl ()` returns a typed promise `Promise <string>` so I should not have to.

Comment: But Typescript doesn't understand that at that point.  As far as it's concerned, it doesn't see a type assigned to `x` so it interprets it as an "implied any", which violates your tsconfig.  You can get past that by either explicitly giving `x` a type of any, or if you know it will always return a `Promise<string>` then you can give it that type.

Comment: TypeScript cannot currently infer the types from that as far as I know.

Comment: That is incorrect. The following compiles and work just fine:
    Promise.resolve('data')
        .then(x => {
            return x;
        });